# weka python wrapper loader for windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, weka, loader, arff, java-bridge-method

I've installed weka python wrapper on Windows 10. And I tried running the sample code:

[image]

but i got this kind of error:

[image]

any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [python-weka-wrapper3](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3) if you want to use it with Python 3. The [python-weka-wrapper](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper) package is for Python 2.7:

You can install it with pip like this:

`pip install python-weka-wrapper3`

Comment: i already got this solution yesterday when i am trying to fix it, but thanks its a great answer!